# Asynchronous multipart uploads to Amazon S3 with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous, amazon-s3, multipart

I am able to initiate asynchronous uploads to S3, however they are somehow not ending up as a file inside my S3 bucket and I see an error *'WithPartETags cannot be empty'*. Here is the complete code

```
InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest =
    new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest()
    .WithBucketName(existingBucketName)
    .WithKey(Path.Combine(S3Path + "/", finfo.Name));

InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse =
    s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

// 2. Upload Parts.
long contentLength = finfo.Length;
long partSize = 15728640;//52428800-50MB 104857600- 100 MB - 5242880 - 5 MB
try
{
    long filePosition = 0;
    for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++)
    {

        // Create request to upload a part.
        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
            .WithBucketName(existingBucketName)
            .WithKey(Path.Combine(S3Path + "/", finfo.Name))
            .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId)
            .WithPartNumber(i)
            .WithPartSize(partSize)
            .WithFilePosition(filePosition)
            .WithFilePath(finfo.FullName);

        // Upload part and add response to our list.
        //uploadResponses.Add(s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest));

        IAsyncResult ar = s3Client.BeginUploadPart(uploadRequest, null, null);
        ListObj.Add(new ThreadList() { _iasyncResult = ar });

        filePosition += partSize;
        Console.WriteLine("Length Written - " + filePosition + " .Content Length - " + contentLength);
    }

    bool uploadsComplete = false;
    while (!uploadsComplete)
    {
        bool individualuploadscomplete = true;
        foreach (var obj in ListObj)
        {
            if (!obj._iasyncResult.IsCompleted)
            {
                individualuploadscomplete = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (individualuploadscomplete)
        {
            uploadsComplete = true;
        }
    }

    foreach (var obj in ListObj)
    {
        s3Client.EndUploadPart(obj._iasyncResult);
    }

    //// Step 3: complete.
    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest =
        new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
        .WithBucketName(existingBucketName)
        .WithKey(Path.Combine(S3Path + "/", finfo.Name))
        .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId);
        //.WithPartETags(uploadResponses);

    CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse =
        s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(compRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you have the setting of the `PartETags` commented out for the complete multipart upload call but you need to add that code back in. Also when you are calling the `EndUploadPart` method you need to capture that `UploadResponse` that comes back from that.

You also might want to look into the [TransferUtility](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility.htm) found in the Amazon.S3.Transfer namespace. Its upload methods are designed to handle what you are attempting to accomplish for large objects, see [Using the High-Level .NET API for Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuDotNet.html) for details and example snippets.